# command difference in Solaris and linux shell

Tags: ubuntu, solaris

i got this snippet from a shell script , it run perfectly in Solaris environment

```
grep -h '??.*??' $1/{CT,{MYDIR{85,97}}{,_E}}/R*txt
```

but when i try to run shell script in ubuntu , it gives following error

```
grep: ./{MYDIR85}/R*txt: No such file or directory
grep: ./{MYDIR85}_E/R*txt: No such file or directory
```

after little bit of editing it run properly, i removed curly braces of MYDIR

```
grep -h '??.*??' $1/{CT,MYDIR{85,97} {,_E}}  /R*txt
```

I want to know what is the problem , is it command incompatibility between linux and solaris ?

Note -i have three directory MYDIR85 , MYDIR97 and CT
     - in ubuntu , shell is   /bin/bash
     - in solaris i don't know the shell type,but the first line of shell     script is #!/bin/bash

Comment: update to include details of shell used on solaris vs linux, e.g. `echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: is $1 set ? curly brace are fine in ubuntu. try setting shopt -s nullglob.

Comment: Sounds like a `csh` thing to me - see for example [Why doesn't bash treat brace expansions exactly like csh?](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/bash/D2.shtml)

Comment: @steve i updated my question

Comment: @Archemar yes i pass dot  .

Comment: From `man bash`, *A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain ... at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression*. Don't know why it is being expanded in Solaris - unless the shell is different.

Comment: @steeldriver i am new to this thing , could you please give an example here , thanks

Comment: Please see below - not a full answer but too big to post as a comment

Answer (score 3):

According to the `bash` manpages

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and
>   closing braces, **and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence
>   expression**.  Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

In your expression `{MYDIR{85,97}}`, the *outer* brace has neither an unquoted comma nor a sequence expression, so is left unexpanded - resulting in `{MYDIR85} {MYDIR97}`. Just for the sake of illustration, you can get the desired behavior by adding a trailing comma:

```
bash $ echo {MYDIR{85,97},}
MYDIR85 MYDIR97
```

although this would introduce an extra - presumably unwanted - `_E` element into your compounded expression `{CT,{MYDIR{85,97}}{,_E}}`.

---

I don't know why you're seeing different behavior under Solaris, except to note that `csh` *does* remove the outer braces under this condition (although it also accepts the trailing comma form - as do `ksh` and `zsh` apparently):

```
csh % echo {MYDIR{85,97}}
MYDIR85 MYDIR97
csh % echo {MYDIR{85,97},}
MYDIR85 MYDIR97
```